# How to obtain the correct sequence number of class parameters in SQL?

Tags: intersystems-cache

Still on the task of reading class elements from SQL using JDBC... And I have a problem with class parameters.

Given those two SQL queries (both in namespace `SAMPLES`):

```
select name, sequenceNumber from %Dictionary.PropertyDefinition
    where parent = 'Sample.Person';

select name, sequenceNumber
    from %Dictionary.ParameterDefinition
    where parent = 'Aviation.Cubes.Aircraft.StarAircraftModel';
```

the first query will correctly report the sequence number in the source file as it has been written.

However, this is not the case for the second query: `sequenceNumber` is always 0!

How do I obtain the "position" of a parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Second query correct as well, but wrong target, because, such behavior possible for generated classes. You can see it by non-empty `GeneratedBy` property in definition for this class. If you try to do it for `Sample.Person` it will shown correctly.

But I still don't understand why you use JDBC, because it's so slow. I am not sure what are you doing, but maybe, my code can help you. [Java class](https://github.com/daimor/NBStudio/blob/master/NBStudioCore/src/org/nbstudio/core/cls/ClassFile.java) for reading Cache classes.

Comment: Well, I use JDBC because at the moment I don't know any better ;) I'll have a look at your project, it looks interesting!

Comment: Hmm, OK, looks like I need another jar in order to use the classes you use in your project... I'll investigate